# Cross-compiling from WSL and Linux causes missing entry point DeleteCriticalSection

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile from WSL and Linux to Win32 using `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`. The program is dependent on some DLL:s that I have downloaded, and are known to work when used for an exe cross-compiled on Cygwin. Compilation and linking works without throwing any errors or warnings, but when I run the resulting executable on Windows (by double-clicking on it in an Explorer window) I get a Windows-error-prompt:

```
The procedure entry point DeleteCriticalSection could not be located in the DLL...
```

and then it points to the program (the `.exe`) itself, not a DLL (message translated from Swedish ;-).

[image]

When I do the exact same thing on Cygwin with the same archive for the DLL:s and the same DLL:s the resulting exe works as it should.

The new(ish) [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) shows some red lines for COMCTL32 and OLEAUT32, but those are the same for both.

A very simple windows GUI app compiles and runs, so it's not the cross-compile as such that is causing the issue. The DLL:s in combination with WSL/Ubuntu/GNU cross-compilation seems to be the culprit.

### Instructions

EDIT: after explicitly following my own instructions and explicitly re-installing the cross-compilation tool-chain the instructions below no longer creates a faulty exe. But the original problem remains.

I'm happy to take any ideas on what to try next.

---

Here are instructions to repeat what I have. Create an empty directory in WSL and run

```
$ sudo apt install binutils-mingw-w64-i686 gcc-mingw-w64-i686
$ wget https://github.com/DavidKinder/Windows-Glk/releases/download/1.50/WindowsGlk-150.zip
$ unzip WindowsGlk-150.zip
```

Then create `startup.c` with the following content

```c
#include <unistd.h>

#include "glk.h"
#include "WinGlk.h"

int winglk_startup_code(const char* cmdline)
{
    return 1;
}

void glk_main(void) {
   sleep(10);
}
```

(Fix the capitalized include of "glk.h" in Glk.c or you'll get an error.)

Compile and link with

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -mwindows -I Include/ Glk.c startup.c Glk.lib
```

to get an `a.exe`. The message only shows up in Gui-mode so you need to run it from an explorer window:

```
explorer.exe .
```

and double-click on `a.exe`.

### WSL and Linux vs. Cygwin

I've done the same cross-compilation on a "real" Ubuntu 20.04 and getting the same problem. Again, doing the exact same steps in Cygwin produces a runable exe. This points to a cross-compilation problem with some facet of
what the exe and the DLL:s are doing. (There is no code in the exe that does anything with critical sections. Could this be an API mismatch?)

Since the DLL:s are the same it is reasonable to suspect the actual cross-compilation of sources in my program.

Is there anything in the cross-compilation toolchain on Linux that might differ? Which Windows run-times and API-versions are targeted?

I'm happy to take any ideas on what to try next.

Comment: I would suggest to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this will augment your chances to get an answer. This would basically be for example  a simple program calling `InitializeCriticalSection()`  and `DeleteCriticalSection()`, along with the exact commands you used for compiling the example.

Comment: Thanks @Frant, I know about those recommendations. Even the smallest reproducible example will contain a lot of specfics and downloads. It is not my code (if any) that calls anything critical section-like, it's somewhere down in those DLL:s, and since they are the same I wondered if someone knew about any WSL cross-compilation differences that could cause this. But I'll add instructions for the simplest reproducible example.